# Uploud File with Selenium/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to uploud a file using Selenium with Python, but for a reason that I don't understand I'm not being able to send the File location using .send_keys("")

I will put here the HTML code of the Uploud Button that is at Portuguese, so it's called "Adicionar Arquivos"

```
<div ng-if="c.showAttachments()" class="wrapper-md row no-margin ng-scope" role="region" aria-label="Anexos"> 
     <!-- ngIf: attachments.length || errorMessages.length --> 
     <div ng-class="{'flex-center attachment-height': options.native_mobile == 'true', 'flex-end': options.native_mobile != 'true'}" class="flex-end"> 
      <!-- ngIf: !submitting && !submitted --><label ng-if="!submitting &amp;&amp; !submitted" style="font-weight:normal;cursor:pointer;" class="ng-scope"> 
       <sp-attachment-button required="required"><span class="file-upload-input"><input type="file" style="display: none" multiple="true" ng-file-select="uploadAttachments($files)" class="sp-attachments-input"><button title="" ng-click="attachmentHandler.openSelector($event)" class="panel-button sp-attachment-add btn btn-link" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" aria-label="Adicionar anexos" data-container="section.page" data-original-title="Adicionar anexos"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span></button></span></sp-attachment-button> <!-- ngIf: data.sc_cat_item.mandatory_attachment --> <span aria-hidden="true">Adicionar anexos</span> </label><!-- end ngIf: !submitting && !submitted --> 
     </div> 
    </div>
```

The way I was trying to do this is by
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CLASS_NAME, "file-upload-input")).send_keys("My File Location")

I expected that this could send the location of my file and would uploud it

Comment: You'll want to target <input type="file"... element.  Right now you're trying to send keys to a <span>...  then use .submit() method on it.